# What is the most efficient way to check if there are any char duplicates in a String?

Tags: java, string

I am trying to find an efficient way to check if there are any duplicate chars in a String. For example, how could I most efficiently check if a String contains more than one period?

My attempt:

```
if (str.indexOf(".") > -1) { //if period '.' exists
    if (str.substring(str.indexOf(".") + 1).indexOf(".") > -1) { //if a second period '.' exists
        return true;
    }
}
return false;
```

edit: By efficient I mean fast and small. Is there a fast, one-line, human readable strategy?

Comment: What does effective mean in your case? Fast or small?

Comment: What do you mean by "most efficient"? If you want to optimize time, you can create a int[256] and count the occurrence of each character for example. If you want to optimize memory, then another algorithm applies etc.

Comment: @ArnaudDenoyelle `int[256]` won't be long enough, as a Java `char` is a 16-bit value, and it's also unnecessarily wide for the question, as you only count up to two. `bool[0x110000]` would suffice for the whole Unicode range.

Comment: easiest way to code would be `return (str.indexOf(".")!=-1 && str.indexOf(".")!=str.lastIndexOf("."));`. Best for time would probably be `int count = 0; for (char c : str.toCharArray()) if (c=='.' && ++count>=2) return true;`

Comment: to your edit - fast is something very different than small. a one-line strategy will probably be slower given that the java compiler has no heavy build-in code optimization

Comment: @msrd0 If you're going for brevity, leave out the first part, simply check `str.indexOf(".")!=str.lastIndexOf("."));` If `indexOf()` returns -1, so will `lastIndexOf()`. It isn't the fastest though, in a worst case scenario this will scan your string twice.

Answer (score 3):

First, don't calculate the same value more than once (`str.indexOf(".")`). Also, creating a throwaway substring is expensive.

There's also a second [`indexOf()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf(int,%20int)) taking a starting index

```
int dot = str.indexOf(".");
if (dot > -1 && str.indexOf(".", dot + 1) > -1)
    return true;

return false;
```

You can shorten this to

```
int dot = str.indexOf(".");
return dot > -1 && str.indexOf(".", dot + 1) > -1;
```

---

There are two different kinds of `indexOf`

- [`indexOf(int ch)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf(int)) and [`indexOf(int ch, int fromIndex)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf(int,%20int))
- [`indexOf(String str)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf(java.lang.String)) and [`indexOf(String str, int fromIndex)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf(java.lang.String,%20int))

I don't know, but I would assume, that searching for a single character is faster than searching for a string. So using the former might be the faster choice.

Answer (score 1):

The problem can be solved in very compact way in Java 8 - or, to be precise, the 2 sub-problems.

1) Checking if there is any character repeated.

```
boolean static containsRepetitions(String s) {
    return s.chars().mapToObj(c -> c).collect(Collectors.toSet()).size() != s.length();
}
```

2) Checking, if the specified character is repeated.

```
boolean static isCharRepeated(String s, char c) {
    return s.chars().filter(x -> x == c).count() > 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can start with the following code:

```
private static final Pattern pat = Pattern.compile(".*?\\..*\\..*");
void yourMethod() {
    System.out.println(pat.matcher("yourString").matches());
}
```

You can also modify regex to find another duplicated chars.

Comment: a regex is definitely not the fastest way, eventhough on modern machines and that easy regex you shouldn't notice the difference

Comment: @msrd0 you are right, I looked into String.indexOf() method and it would be probably the best choice. Howewer using regex it is quite easy to find any duplicates.